# Word 2007/2010: select table by keyboard (no numeric keypad)

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

In Word 2007/2010, how can I select a table or portions (column, row, cell) by only using the keyboard?

I don't have a numeric keypad, so things like `Ctrl + NUM 5` do not work.

--jeroen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Word 2007 use `<alt> <jl> <k> <t>`

this goes through the Table tools>Layout>Select>"Table" menu options

Comment: This is exactly what I meant.